# Identify repeat buyers in Excel

Tags: excel

I have a list of about 15,000 purchase records in an Excel table.  About 3,000 of them are repeat orders (I can see this when I use the "remove duplicates" function in Excel).

My goal is to display a list of the customers who created those 3,000 repeat orders.  For example, maybe 300 customers placed 10 orders each, so my output should show a list of those 300 customers.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you mean the output should show a list of those **300** customers?

Comment: But Remove Duplicates doesn't do what you want? There's a [filter with copy answer on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/a/49620/39645) - is that more what you want?

Comment: yes, thanks @dustytrash

Answer (score 1):

Using formulas:

```
=IF(AND(COUNTIF(A$1:A$10,A1)>1,COUNTIF(A$1:A$10,A1)=COUNTIF(A1:A$10,A1)),A1, "")
```

And populate down (my sample had 10 rows, adjust the formula as needed first)

You can then filter on that column to hide blank cells and leave only the names of the clients